# I dont't understand "ValueError: not enough values to unpack"

Tags: python, python-3.x, valueerror

I'm learning Python 3 and I'm on an exercise that allows (on a string) to alternate uppercase and lowercase letters. Unfortunately I get an error and I don't understand what it means.

Can someone explain to me, when you get this type of message "ValueError: not enough values to unpack", where can the error come from? Thank you in advance!

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/python3.6
#Une lettre sur deux en majuscule, les autres en minuscules !
#Yeah ! Tu PeUx Le FaIrE !!! \o/

a = input("Ecris ce que tu veux : ")


for i, b in a:
    if i == i.upper and b == b.lower:
        print(a)
```

And here's the error message:

```
    for i, b in a:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: You iterate so each time you have single character. Then you are trying split it into two values.

Answer (score 0):

What @miszcz2137 means is that  each time you go through your for loop you you get a character:

First iteration you get: "E" 
Second iteration you got: "c"
Third iteration you got: "r"
...
and you code "tries" to split these characters into 2 but as there is only one character, an Error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is some text, like `"some text"`. If you then write `for i, b in a`, it will perform a loop over all the characters in the iterable string `a`, i.e. it would call the code inside your for-loop for every letter of `"some text"`. Then, you're trying to assign such a letter to a tuple of two variables, `(i, b)` which is not possible. This is what the error message is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a string. You can use it in `for` loops to get each character:

```
for b in a:
  print(b)  # b is each char every time
```

If you want the index too, use this code:

```
for i, b in enumerate(a):
  print(i, b)
```

But if you desire to have each char against all the chars to compare or anything else like that, it's better to use two `for`s instead:

```
for i in a:
  for b in a:
    if i == i.upper() and b == b.lower():
        print(i, b)
```